# Django reverse relations serialization

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, relational-database

I have many-to-many relations and I want to serialize reverse relations.

Here are my models:

```
class Nutrition(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Company(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
   nutritions = models.ManyToManyField(Nutrition, blank=True, related_name="companyID")

   def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

And here are my serializers:

```
class NutritionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  companyID = CompanySerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Nutrition
    fields=('id', 'name', 'companyID')

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  nutritions_list = NutritionSerializer(source="nutritions", read_only=True, many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'nutritions_list')
```

And I'm getting an error:

> NameError: name 'CompanySerializer' is not defined

Comment: won't this return a ***"Infinite nested serialized"*** result, will it?

Comment: I don't know). 'Direct relations' (in my case nutritions_list) works as expected. I don't know how to deal with reverse...

Comment: NameError is something you have got from Python itself.

Comment: What does it mean ? It seems that i didn't misstype something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the name error because you call `CompanySerializer`:

```
class NutritionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    companyID = CompanySerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    ...
```

before defining it (a couple of lines under):

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
```

What i would suggest doing is adding another serializer for `Company` which does not include `NutritionSerializer` so you can place it above both `NutritionSerializer` and `CompanySerializer`. Here is how it would look:

```
class SimpleCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class NutritionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = SimpleCompanySerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Nutrition
        fields=('id', 'name', 'company')

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nutritions_list = NutritionSerializer(source="nutritions", read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'nutritions_list')
```

Comment: No way. The solution is so simple...Couldn't figure it out more than a day and a half.

Comment: Glad i could help :D